# Best practice to store password in xml security-context.xml or database?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-security, hashcode

Good day developers.
I have question. In my web application I use spring security. I have 2 simple ROLE: User, Admin. For each of those rules I have his own password because the all have different access to my web-app. So I store all passwords now in security.xml in sha-256 hash encoding:

```
    <security:http pattern="/search" security="none" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" >

    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/input" access="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/delete" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/> 

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
                         authentication-failure-url="/loginfail"
                         default-target-url="/input" 
                         always-use-default-target="true" 
                         username-parameter="j_username"
                         password-parameter="j_password" />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>

        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>

    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
    <security:user-service>
    <security:user name="user" password="04f8996da763b7a969b1028ee3007569eaf3a635486ddab211d512c85b9df8fb" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:user name="admin" password="8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Does it really good idea? Maybe it is required to store them just in DB(H2 for example) for more protection.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"> <!-- Using and configuring C3P0 proxy -->
        <property name="driverClass"><value>org.h2.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>jdbc:h2:/home/vadim/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/h2/EDUCATION</value></property>
        <property name="user"><value>sa</value></property>
        <property name="password" ><value></value></property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>3</value></property> <!-- Number of Connections a pool will try to acquire upon startup -->
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>1</value></property> <!-- Minimum connection pool size -->
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>20</value></property> <!-- Max connection pool size -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge"><value>3600</value></property> <!-- Set max connection age to 1 hour, after it will release -->
        <property name="maxIdleTime"><value>600</value></property> <!-- 10 minutes connection can stay unused before be discarded -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout"><value>200000</value></property> <!-- Each what time check for unused connections -->
        </bean>
```

Now my password is blank, but I should have one. How to protect it??

Thank you.

Comment: Your best protection is by securing your data storage. Whether that's a database, flat file, or anything else is irrelevant. If that's exposed, it's really just a matter of time before passwords may start being found.

Comment: Ok I use database in my app-config.xml where I configuring datasource and I really don't know how to hide it. Corresponding to your reply how can I protect it. For more understanding I add will add my app-config.xml. Thank you Colin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new BCryptPasswordEncoder:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html

It will salt your passwords for you automatically.

I recommend BCrypt as it is strong, and slow, and has no known weaknesses. "Slowness" is actually a feature you want in a hashing algorithm, because that means it takes a longer time to crack if someone steals your passwords.

SHA 256 is [weakened](http://valerieaurora.org/hash.html). MD5 is definitely broken.

The advantage of storing users/hashed passwords in the xml file is simplicity. However you would need to restart your application to make a change. Also, no user self-management.

There is an `encode` method on the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` that will let you encode your passwords for storage in xml or the database.

Comment: Sir let me please ask you. I have to BCrypt my plain password like "user" for example and after create bean  BCryptPasswordEncoder for recognize my password when user input it as plaintext. Right??

Comment: The article you linked addresses the weakness of using a hash as an address due to collisions. Hashing passwords is a totally different ball game.

Answer (score 0):

When you store a password, you must at least hash it (several times, for example, 1000) and salt it.

Hashing several times is essential because if someone tries to beak the password, he will also need to hash the input as many time as you did : it makes the hacker loose time.

Salting prevents a hacker from using a reverse table of hashed passwords.

You should also use a different salt for every user.

Here, with your password encrypted in the configuration file without any salt, I would just use a reverse table to find the corresponding password.

**EDIT**: actually, I tried. Your first password is "**user**". Your second password is "**admin**". I got them using this simple publicly available [reverse table](http://sha-256.sha1-lookup.com/).

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't encrypt passwords at all, you should _hash_ them. Encryption is reversible, hashing is not. Second of all, you should not just "repeat it several times". You can `md5` a password 2000 times if you want, it's no more secure than once. The hacker doesn't have to hash it 2000 times, (s)he just needs to find another input that generates the same hash when `md5`'d. You should use a multi-round cryptographically secure algorithm such as blowfish

Comment: But how it's suppose to work(salting and crypting) if I just have preinstalled password in my security.xml?? I thought I can't use salting just because it generates password when I have registration system for my users who willing to use my web app. adding random character to inputed password?? Do I miss something? And Crypting, what about it? Hash is not enough? As I know it one way hiding my password and to hard to have it back to plaintext?

Comment: @Colin Ok for hashing, I edited. For the second part, I don't agree. The purpose of breaking the password is to be able to use it to log in in the system. The login you will enter will be hashed 2000 times by the system, so you need to hash 2000 times to ensure that hashed password will correspond. btw, I take this advice from `www.owasp.org`.

Comment: @USER_JVM : I don't know the options provided by spring security but if you use this configuration, it's clearly unsafe as it took my 30s to find your passwords. You might prefer Apache Shiro to handle your security.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle That's correct. I'm sorry, I was speaking of something different. The 2000th time is no more _crpytographically secure_ than the first, but you are correct that it would take longer to brute force.

Comment: Yes I did not try to install secure pass cuz I'm just trying to configure and understand how everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have two users hard coded to the two roles. Everyone who uses the application should be an individual user with their own username and password. The individual users will have one or both roles.

With this in mind its obvious that you need to store user data in a database. Your user table should have the username, hashed password, salt and any other fields you need.

You should have another table with roles in it, and another table which maps users to roles.

When a user is created you should generate salt using a cryptographic random generator such as  [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). The hashed password is created using a hashing algorithm and the salt, spring security has a [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html) that does this (it also supports multiple hashing iterations).

I would recommend reading the spring security docs, specifically http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-providers

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sir. My application will be controlled from one place, like this place responsible to put data into database and delete them. Other part of application this search page witch will have no security. It's responsible to search  data in DB stored in that place. I protected delete page jsp access for admin only and input page jsp user role and admin role.  How can  bind salt + HASH for my  PERMANENT passwords for user and admin declared in security.xml. Can't understand this.